# AWS cloudfront serves outdated content in Google Chrome?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront, cache-invalidation

I have a react app installed in AWS s3. And I am serving the content using AWS CloudFront.
I have made some changes in the app and did invalidation in the CloudFront. It is serving updated content in all browsers excpet Google Chrome. Google Chrome loads the page with the old content.
Could you please let me know why it's happening?

Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

Can you please check if your caching is managed on the cloudfront level or the client level?
Did you try to clear the browser cache? Because if your caching is being handled on the client level then clearing the browser cache should show you the updated content.